# R: How can I make a heatmap color scale graded only on one side?

Tags: r, pheatmap

I am generating a heatmap using pheatmap in r. I am plotting the false discovery rate corrected p-value that are signed based on up-regulated or down-regulated from the fold change. I would like the color scale to be graded from -0.1 to 0. Then switch colors at 0 and be graded again from 0 to 0.1. How can I make the color scale graded only on one side?

```
data=read.csv("metabolism_heatmap.csv")
rownames(data)=data$Gene
data$Category=as.character(data$Category)
data=data[order(data$Category),]
#rows 1-29 = one category
#cols 11-12 = signed FDR-value for 2 groups of samples
colors2<- colorRampPalette(c("white", "blue", "red", "white"))(n = 100)
pheatmap(data[1:29,c(11,12)], 
     color= colors2,
     cluster_rows = FALSE,
     breaks = seq(-0.1,0.1,length.out = 101))
```

Here is the plot. I want to get rid of the purple and have a sharp boundary at zero.
[Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8nL7.png)